# Backbone.js & Flask RESTful API (OPTIONS request only)

Tags: rest, backbone.js, flask

Hi stackoverflow community.

I'm working on the Book Library example of the "[Developing Backbone.js Applications](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#exercise-2-book-library---your-first-restful-backbone.js-app)" book and I did the RESTful API with flask+peewee. Backbone.js just does a single OPTIONS request and nothing more.

This is the API specs:

```
url             HTTP Method  Operation
/api/books      GET          Get an array of all books
/api/books/:id  GET          Get the book with id of :id
/api/books      POST         Add a new book and return the book with an id attribute added
/api/books/:id  PUT          Update the book with id of :id
/api/books/:id  DELETE       Delete the book with id of :id
```

This is the main code:

```
@app.route('/api/books', methods=['DELETE', 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
@app.route('/api/books/<int:book_id>', methods=['DELETE', 'GET', 'PUT'])
def books(book_id=None):
    if book_id:
        if request.method == 'DELETE':
            Book.delete().where(Book.id == book_id).execute()

        elif request.method == 'GET':
            book = Book.get(id=book_id)
            return jsonify(get_attr(book))

        elif request.method == 'PUT':
            book = Book.get(id=book_id)
            book.update(**parse_attr(request)).execute()

    else:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return jsonify([get_attr(entry) for entry in Book.select()])

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            new_book = Book(**parse_attr(request))
            new_book.save()
            return jsonify(get_attr(new_book))

    return '', 200
```

This is the respond's header for the OPTIONS request:

```
#curl -I -X OPTIONS  http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/books
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE
Content-Length: 0
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.4 Python/2.7.3
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 20:29:07 GMT
```

I hope someone can help me with this, it took until 4 a.m. to get tired and hit the sack with a frustration feeling...

PS: I apologize for my bad English, it is a second language for me.

~~~ UPDATE: 2013/01/10 ~~~

./js/views/library.js

```
var app = app || {};

app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#books',

    initialize: function(initialBooks) {
        this.collection = new app.Library(initialBooks);
        this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
        this.render();

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },

    events: {
        'click #add': 'addBook'
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
            this.renderBook(item);
        }, this);
    },

    renderBook: function(item) {
        var bookView = new app.BookView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append(bookView.render().el)
    },

    addBook: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = {};

        $('#addBook div').children('input').each(function(i, el) {
            if($(el).val() != '') {
                formData[el.id] = $(el).val();
            }
        });

        this.collection.add(new app.Book(formData));
        //this.collection.create(formData);
    },
});
```

./js/views/book.js

```
var app = app || {};

app.BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'bookContainer',
    template: _.template($('#bookTemplate').html()),

    events: {
        'click .delete': 'deleteBook'
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    deleteBook: function() {
        this.model.destroy();
        this.remove();
    }
});
```

./js/collections/library.js

```
var app = app || {};

app.Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Book,
    url: ' http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/books'
});
```

./js/app.js

```
var app = app || {};

$(function() {
    new app.LibraryView();
});

./models/book.js
var app = app || {};

app.Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        coverImage: 'img/placeholder.png',
        title: 'No title',
        author: 'Unknown',
        releaseDate: 'Unknow',
        keywords: 'None'
    }
});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting on the JavaScript side?  (If you are not getting any, what happens when you manually `POST` a new book to your endpoint using curl?)

Comment: Hi Sean, I'm not getting any errors at all. I test every method with curl and all of them works as they should. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If they work with curl then the issue is most likely with your JavaScript - can you post that?

Comment: Sure, I'll do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

In `js/views/library.js` you are using `Collection.add` rather than `Collection.create`, which means the model is never synced with the server.  Either call `Collection.sync` on your `Library` or directly `save` the new model.

Comment: It didn't work... Even after fetch the code from the book (and writing the right url) it didn't work; Backbone.js just send OPTIONS request... I guess the problem is at my flask code...